# Use like operator in session.query in SQLAlchemy with request.args.get

Tags: python, ajax, sqlalchemy, request

I am successfully able to get results from the database using an equal to operator using below query:

```
return session.query(Employees).filter_by(EmployeeName=request.args.get('Name'))
```

Employees is the class

'Name' attribute gets filled via an ajax call

I am not sure how to use like operator instead of equal to?

I tried doing something like this but to no avail

```
return session.query(Employees).filter(Employees.EmployeeName.like(request.args.get('%Name%')))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a shortcut to a simple `'%' || expr || '%'` comparison use the [`contains()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.contains) method provided by `ColumnOperators`:

```
session.query(Employees).\
    filter(Employees.EmployeeName.contains(request.args.get('Name')))
```

Note that possible wildcard characters are not escaped, so if *Name* contains them, they'll behave as such.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `request.args.get('Name')` is your way of returning the name.  Putting `%` around name in that case is going to return a wrong (probably empty) arg from request.  Instead, try formatting a string with the result:

```
return session.query(Employees).filter(Employees.EmployeeName.like("%{0}%".format(request.args.get('Name')))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but that did not work for me.

Comment: Could I see your model object for Employees?  I might be able to help a bit better.