# sqlalchemy: Passign a form input to a filter does not return any results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
db = create_engine('mysql://usr:passwd@localhost/DB', 
isolation_level="READ UNCOMMITTED")
metadata = MetaData(db)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db)
session = Session()
server = Table('server', metadata, autoload=True)

if (model is not None):
  # The below == works and returns results
  #s = session.query(server).filter(server.c.product == model)
  #This returns nothing
  s = session.query(server).filter(server.c.product.like("%model%")).all()
```

model is passed as a form parameter

```
@app.route('/serverHandleList', methods=['POST'])
def serverHandleList():
model = request.form['inputModelName']
serverItems = getModel(model)

return render_template('some.html', items=serverItems, name=model)
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use like operator in session.query in SQLAlchemy with request.args.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995599/use-like-operator-in-session-query-in-sqlalchemy-with-request-args-get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently searching for the word "model" *instead* of what's being passed in the variable `model`.

Change to this instead:

```
  s = session.query(server).filter(server.c.product.like("%{}%".format(model))).all()
```

Comment: Oops such a blooper on my part. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: It's ok we all make mistakes. You're very welcome. Happy coding to you!